# How to find subdirectory named "qt5/plugins"

Tags: find

I need to find the Qt plugins directory, and I've spent an hour looking for a way to find directory names that include a /. There is a ton of 'qt' and if 'qt/plugins' is wrong, I'll need a different format, so I need a general search solution for directory name including a /.

For example, bin/yelp exists on my computer (which I'm using as a test), and none of the command syntaxes I've found with Google will find that.

Ordinarily, I would just figure something like this out, but I've spent over an hour on this.

Comment: No directory nor file in Linux can have `/` in the name, because `/` is the character that **separates** directory names. `qt/plugins` means a directory (or file) called `plugins` that is located in the directory called `qt`. So strictly speaking, you have to first search for the directory called `qt`, and after you find it, search for the directory called `plugins` **inside** that directory.

Comment: The `/` isn't part of the filename - it's a separator between directories. "`qt5/plugins`" describes the entity (file, directory, link, ...) named "`plugins`", contained in the directory "`qt5`".

Comment: @raj The posted answer works.  I installed and used mlocate, and just ran 'mlocate qt5/plugins' and it listed the matching directories.

Comment: @Richard83 Yes, the answer works, but you have to understand what you are searching for. You are **not** searching for a directory `qt5/plugins`, but for a directory `plugins` inside directory `qt5`. It's like you are not searching for car that is red and green, but for a red car that is behind a green car. Knowing this beforehand, you would take a different approach to searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locate` seems to be the most helpful command here:

```
$ locate bin/yelp
/usr/bin/yelp
```

and

```
$ locate qt| grep plugins
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/bearer
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/egldeviceintegrations
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/generic
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/iconengines
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/imageformats
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platformthemes
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/styles
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqgenericbearer.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/bearer/libqnmbearer.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-emu-integration.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-integration.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-x11-integration.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/generic/libqevdevkeyboardplugin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/generic/libqevdevmouseplugin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/generic/libqevdevtabletplugin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/generic/libqevdevtouchplugin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/generic/libqlibinputplugin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/generic/libqtuiotouchplugin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libcomposeplatforminputcontextplugin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libibusplatforminputcontextplugin.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk3.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platformthemes/libqt5ct.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/styles/libqt5ct-style.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-egl-integration.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
```

or if you only want it ending on plugins:

```
$ locate qt| grep 'plugins$'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins
```

`locate` has 1 issue:it is basing its results from a database it maintains and that database is not real-time but it is built every so often. `updatedb` updates it.

Comment: locate was not installed.  Ubuntu suggested I install mlocate, which works.  Thank you. -- (Now why were all of my Google searches giving extremely complicated attempts and using 'find' ??? - when this is so simple ???)  I just used 'mlocate qt5/plugins' - and now I see where it is.

Comment: @Richard83 as @Rinzwind noted, `locate` returns results from a database of filenames that is updated (by default) once per day. So if the file was created after last update, `locate` won't find it, and if it was deleted after the last update, `locate` will still find it despite it doesn't exist anymore. On the contrary, `find` performs a live, actual filesystem search and finds only the files/directories that actually exist.

Comment: @Richard83 find is perfect for finding files but when combined with regexes can also become very difficult

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use the `find` command - using the `-path` predicate in place of the usual `-name` (which can never match a pattern containing a `/` path separator). For example:

```
find / -path '*/qt/plugins' 2>/dev/null
```

The leading `*/` is required because `-path` matches against the *whole* path.

You could also use `find / -regex '.*/qt/plugins' 2>/dev/null` (again matching against the whole path, with `.*` taking the place of the shell glob's `*` wildcard) however a regular expression has no advantage for such a simple pattern.